# Reading data from file C++

Tags: c++

I have these set of data in `.txt` log file:

```
2016-01-17 Red 1 2 2.252016-01-18 blue 3 1 1.34
```

I stored it to vector, and the code looks like this:

```
while(!logFile.eof()) {
    getline(logFile, l.date, ' ');
    getline(logFile, l.color, ' ');
    logFile >> l.minUsage;
    logFile >> l.maxUsage;
    logFile >> l.ratio;
    logFile.ignore(1000, ' ');

    log.push_back(l);
}
```

log's datatype is `vector<Record>` where `Record` is a class. I wanted the values to look like this when I'm printing it:

```
2016-01-17 Red  1 2 2.25
2016-01-18 blue 3 1 1.34
```

but instead I got this output:

```
2016-01-17 Red  1 2 2.25
blue 3 1 0 1.34
```

the second line doesn't store the value of the date from second set of data from `.txt` file.

How to separate the `2.252016-01-18` from the `.txt` file into 2 different entries like `2.25` and `2016-01-18` ?

Comment: `2016-01-17 Red 1 2 2.252016-01-18 blue 3 1 1.34` - is that really your data? No delimiter?

Comment: yes, no separator. the data is like that. that's why i got this problem

Comment: `getline` gets the entire line, which, according to your example, will read all the data for a record. All the other file input operations are moot.

Comment: @HSK2609 The laziest way is to read the whole file into a `std::string` and insert `\n` before every date (except the first one). You can use regex for that, or just search for `2016` if appears only as a year in the file. No `Record` class, assuming that you just want to reformat a large file.

Comment: Read in `l.ratio` token  and look backwards for for `'-'`. If no `'-'`, no date. Carry on. If `'-'`, look back further for the next one and then count back 4 more characters to get the year. Split here and store date for next read. If date stored, use it, clear it and read for colour. If no date stored, read for date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved. since the value of `ratio` in the log file are all 3 digit decimal, so i changed the type of `ratio` to only accept 4 characters (example: `2.13`), then i deleted the `logFile.ignore(1000, ' ');` line. it works and it gives me the result i wanted.

Comment: Even better than my pitch. On the `logFile.ignore(1000, ' ');` bit, the rule of thumb is to use `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` instead of a hard-coded number.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `!logFile.eof()` to test the end of input it doesn't return `true` at the end of input.  Use `getline` instead, something like:

```
while ((getline(logFile, l.date, ' ') && (getline(logFile, l.color, ' ')) {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a simple state machine and extract by space delimited strings:

```
enum Group { DATE_ALONE, COLOR, NUM1, NUM2, NUM3_AND_DATE };

Group state = Group::DATE_ALONE;
std::string str{};
while (logFile >> str) {
    switch (state) {
    case Group::DATE_ALONE:
        auto date = makeDateFromString(str);
        doSomethingWith(date);
        state = Group::COLOR;
        break;
    case Group::COLOR:
        auto color = makeColorFromString(str);
        doSomethingWith(color);
        state = Group::NUM1;
        break;
    // etc...
    case Group::NUM3_AND_DATE:
        auto num = makeNumFromString(str.substr(0, 4));
        doSomethingWith(num);
        auto date = makeDateFromString(str.substr(4));
        doSomethingWith(date);
        state = Group::COLOR; // Skip the `DATE_ALONE` state
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some fudge work required on the part of OP to make this fit their exact circumstances, but right idea and close enough for an upvote.